# Android Java: Region Subtraction

Tags: java, android, region

Is it possible to subtract one [Region](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html) object and subtract it from another?

E.g. I have a two Regions, region1 (green) and region2 (red):

[image]

How would I create a region3 that is only the part of region1 that is not also part of region2 (only green and NOT red)?

Comment: If you add `!` before the link tag like this: `![img](link)`, it loads the image.

Comment: I tried. It wouldn't let me... This was my first question.

Comment: ah OK! I thought it allowed it for first posts' as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Region r1;
    Region r2;
    Region r3 = new Region(r1); // make a copy to not change r1
    r3.op(r2, Op.DIFFERENCE); // r3 = r1-r2
```

If you're not bothered about changing `r1`, obviously you can skip the copy.